# Помогите разобраться где ошибка, я посчитал должно получаться 2.46, а выводит в программе другое

Tags: c

1 задание

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
float y,x,m;

m = 0;
for(x = 99;x >= 3;x=x-3){
    m = sqrt(m+sqrt(x));
}
printf("m = %f",m);
```

Comment: кто-то может обьяснить пожалуйста

Comment: Что получается на первой итерации? Правильно ли срабатывает условие останова на float? Что мешает вставит код текстом?

Comment: А почему m в начале равен 0? Не 96?

Comment: У вас на каждой итерации цикла вычисляется `sqrt` внутри `sqrt`. Откуда взялась такая двойная вложенность `sqrt`? Сразу очевидно, что это совершенно неправильно. На каждой итерации такого цикла уровень вложенности `sqrt` должен быть равен 1. И что такое `main()`??? В языке С требуется `int main(void)`, а не `main()`. И почему вы используете тип `float`? И где `#include <math.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double calc(unsigned v)
{
    if (v == 99) return sqrt(99);
    return sqrt(v + calc(v+3));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("res = %f\n", calc(3));
    return 0;
}
```

Или с циклом:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double r = sqrt(99);
    for (unsigned i = 96; i >= 3; i -= 3){
        r = sqrt(i + r);
    }
    printf("res = %f\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как обьяснил препод , то , что код короткий и должен скорее всего использоваться for , т.к мы его сейчас проходим.
И извините , что засоряю ваш форум, мне реально не куда больше обратиться

Comment: Вот! Пожалуйста!